# Using A3 Token (Safenet 5100) in Ubuntu

Tags: certificates

The company where I work is upgrading the certificates for VPN access from A1 to A3, but I am having trouble getting the new A3 Token to work in Ubuntu.

By following a bunch of instructions from around the web and from coworkers, here is what I have done so far:

1. I have downloaded and installed the driver from the address below.

```
    $ wget https://www.globalsign.com/en/safenet-drivers/USB/10.7/Safenet_Linux_Installer_DEB_x64.zip
```

2. At that point, the token was still not being recognized. It did not appear as a result of the command `p11tool --list-tokens`. So I was told to create the file `/etc/gnutls/pkcs11.conf` and add the following line to it `load=/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so`.
3. That made the token be recognized, but its Module was not being displayed. Here's how it appeared. URL and serial have been purposely removed.

```
    $ p11tool --list-tokens

    Token 1:
        URL: ###########
        Type: Hardware token
        Flags: RNG, Requires login
        Manufacturer: SafeNet, Inc.
        Model: eToken
        Serial: ###########
        Module:
```

4. To solve that, I was told to access the folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11`, delete or rename the file `opensc-pkcs11.so`, and recreate it as symbolic link to the driver's file. That's what I did via the command below.

```
    $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libeToken.so.10.7.77 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

This is pretty much where I stand. Doing step 4 made the token recognize its driver. The Module now appears when I list it.

```
    $ p11tool --list-tokens

    Token 1:
        URL: ###########
        Type: Hardware token
        Flags: RNG, Requires login
        Manufacturer: SafeNet, Inc.
        Model: eToken
        Serial: ###########
        Module: opensc-pkcs11.so
```

But when I try to get the URL of the token's certificate, which I need to access the VPN, this is what I get. Does anyone know how can I fix this?

```
$ p11tool --list-all-certs "[token-url]"

No matching objects found
```

Answer (score 2):

Long time ago...

1. First you need type the command below
   an get a similar response (token serial is masked):

```
$ p11tool --list-all-certs
warning: no token URL was provided for this operation; the available tokens are:

pkcs11:model=p11-kit-trust;manufacturer=PKCS%2311%20Kit;serial=1;token=System%20Trust
pkcs11:model=eToken;manufacturer=SafeNet%2C%20Inc.;serial=0a2a4a6a;token=Soluti
```

2. Then, you can replace `[token-url]`
   with the last line showed (in my case)
   in your `$ p11tool --list-all-certs "[token-url]"`.

---

For example, this is my way to get VPN connection:

```
$ sudo openconnect \
--authgroup=MY_AUTH_GROUP \
--protocol=gp \
MY_VPN_HOSTNAME \
--cafile certificates.pem \
-u MY_USERNAME \
-c $(p11tool --provider=/usr/lib/libeToken.so --list-all-certs --only-urls | tail -1)
```

See the last line:
I added `--only-urls` and filtered to get the last line ( `| tail -1`).

And I needed to specify my provider library (`--provider=/usr/lib/libeToken.so`)
because `p11tool` does not *automagically* locate it.

**Important:** The `PC/SC Smart Card Daemon` needs to be active:
`$ sudo systemctl start pcscd`

Best regards!

Comment: For anyone trying to get access to smart cards on WSL2, the "systemctl start pcscd" tip is golden, start on WSL2 with "pcscd".